# What are the on-disk data directories for Hyperledger Fabric?

Tags: hyperledger-fabric

I am currently running Fabric 1.4 on a machine with a HDD. I have plugged in a SSD. 
I want to achieve better throughput making use of this SSD. But I am not sure what are the data directories or maybe some on-disk access by Golevel db. 
What directories do I need to mount on the SSD to get an optimum performance?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For the peer, the ledger files (as well as the data files for  goleveldb) are created under the `peer.fileSystemPath` directory (default value is `/var/hyperledger/production`).  You can set this value in `core.yaml`.

For the orderer, it's `FileLedger.Location` with default `/var/hyperledger/production/orderer`.  You can set this value in `orderer.yaml`.